# Rails 4 text_area HTML being escaped

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, textarea, fields-for

I have a very peculiar issue. I'm upgrading an app from old Rails 2 up to Rails 4. Here's a small section of code giving me a little difficulty:

```
<h2>Heading</h2>

<%= f.fields_for :contact_notes do |field_form| %>
  <%= field_form.text_area :notes, :no_label => true, :class => "" %>
<% end %>
```

Note that `f` is defined for the main form this is in. There are numerous other fields in this particular partial referenced from `f.` which are all working properly.

What's happening with the above `text_area` is that the HTML for the `text_area` is being HTML escaped, so I'm seeing this on the view instead of an empty text area box:

```
<textarea class="" id="contact_notes" name="contact[contact_attributes][general_notes]" no_label="true"> </textarea>
```

What could be causing this? There are some jQuery functions which manipulate the class under certain cases. But these work fine in Rails 2. I don't know of any way jQuery could literally cause the entire `textarea` HTML to be escaped. I'm looking for ideas on what I can check.

Answer (score 0):

Where is `f` defined:

```
<%= f.fields_for :contact_notes do |field_form| %>
```

This worked fine for me without the "f" so I am not sure what else to recommend without seeing the model/controller.

Comment: `f` is defined as a form variable outside of the partial that my problematic code is in. All the other `f.blah` fields behave as expected. What in the model or controller could cause the `text_area` to output incorrectly?